# I don't understand multi-threaded programming

Tags: multithreading

Can someone please explain to me how a multi-threaded application can be faster when a single core cpu can only do a single thing at a time. If I have 10 threads then only 1 of those threads is really 'running' at any given moment on a single core cpu and all the extra threads just add context switching overhead. So if each thread has 10 instructions to process then in the end I'm still processing 100 instructions sequentially plus the context switching overhead. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the fact that a process might BLOCK to wait for I/O. So, if you use only ONE THREAD in your application, if it blocks to wait for I/O to finish, it will be extremely slow.

On the other hand, if you have multiple threads, your application might have a couple of them waiting for I/O to finish, but the rest of them "executing" while OS gives it access to the SINGLE PROCESSOR.

Do keep in mind that I/O operations compared to CPU operations are **orders of magnitude** slower.

And **yes**. Even in single cores, a multithreaded application will probably be faster than a single threaded one. Consider the case of a server process like APACHE running on a single thread. Every time there is a connection waiting for I/O to finish, the rest of the connection will halt waiting for that I/O operation to finish. Of course there is ASYNC-IO. But the programming model to make a huge server like Apache running on a single thread with ASYNC-IO, will be too complicated to maintain, improve or anything else.

Comment: Additionally, a lot of modern single-core CPUs support HyperThreading, which can speed up multi-threaded applications.

Comment: Ok, this explains some of it but now you are saying something about blocking I/O and that pinpoints the source of my confusion. So are you saying that once the cpu dispatches an I/O request it doesn't have to wait for that request to finish to do other things not related to that request?

Comment: @davidk01: CORRECT. If the OS kernel dispatches an I/O request, will give the processor to another THREAD/PROCESS **immediately**. It makes no sense to waste CPU time while waiting for something SO SLOW like I/O operations...

Comment: this is the best answer but I think you overstate the likelihood of MT apps probably being faster.  It's totally workload-dependent.  A calculation app (Excel for financial data say) will run slower on single core if it dumbly spawns threads to parallelize the calcs.

Answer (score 16):

**A Helpful Analogy About Bananas**

Imagine a supermarket with 4 checkout lanes.  But there is only one cashier.  Should she work on a single register or work on all 4 registers, moving between them?

The obvious answer is that she should stay on one register to avoid wasting time moving between checkout lanes.

But now imagine that when you buy fruit, the scale can take up to 5 minutes to re-calibrate for each specific type of fruit.

While the scale is recalibrating and the register is tied up, suddenly it becomes more efficient overall to rotate over to the next lane and ring up some items there rather than just waiting for the scale to be ready again.

The scale calibrating is non-CPU work (such as disk I/O, network latency, etc.).  Rotating to the next register is switching to another thread.  And there you have it.

Comment: AWESOME analogy! Stackoverflow rocks.

Comment: I was missing the fact that I/O controllers can do things independently from the CPU and things make more sense now.

Comment: That's actually a really good analogy.  I'll have to remember that.

Comment: Nice analogy. One I like to use is a waiter servicing tables. It makes no sense for a waiter to sit there watching people at one table eat just in case they need something, while everyone else waiting for service starves. When one table is engaged in some blocking operation, like deciding what to order or arguing over the check, the waiter can provide service to another table.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's not faster on a single-core processor.  Most programs do many things at once.  Most of these operations are 'bursty' for the processor.  They do something, wait for input or output to finish, then do some more.  Multithreaded programming allows another operation to use the processor during the wait.  Remember, all processors basically do the same thing.  The difference is the speed that they can do their operations.  The goal then is to keep the processor busy doing useful stuff as much as possible.  Multithreaded programming is just a method that makes it easier for programmers to get to that goal.

Comment: Wrong, performance on single core can be faster if threads are in wait state a lot (eg. database client)

Answer (score 0):

On a single core, of course it is not faster. But it can make the system more responsive, by not appearing dead to the world while doing a long-running task.

Comment: Wrong, performance on single core can be faster if threads are in wait state a lot (eg. database client)

Comment: Agreed, but that's more of a programming model issue than a threading issue. You could have a single-threaded stack managing wait states do that as well. (Not that you would want to, of course).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on that what the threads are doing. If there is a relative big amount of latency, another thread can do its job while other threads are waiting for "themselves".